# script convert files using dos2unix

Tags: scripts

I want to create a script to monitorize my local folder and every time it receives a file starting with `frm*`, to convert it using `dos2unix`.

This script is always running and keeps converting the same files, that are already converted, so I think that might be possible an improvement.

What I have now:

```
while true
do    
    dos2unix //path_to_folder/frm*    
done
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: [1]the source files and the converted file, do they stay in the same directory? [2] what is normally the command to convert a single file? Something like: `dos2unix <source> <destination> or simply dos2unix <file>

Comment: Jacob, the file remains the same and in the same folder. just want to convert it to dos2unix (simply dos2unix <file>)

Comment: One more question: what happens with name of the converted files, is their name starting with frm as well?

Comment: This is purely a conversion...the frm2014_1.txt will remain as frm2014_1.txt

Comment: This would probably be a good use-case for `inotifywait`

Comment: @steeldriver, then you would still need to write a section to separate the new files from the existing ones. It is basically the same as writing it out.

Comment: Djames, could you give us some feedback on the answers, did one or both work for you, did you run into problems etc.? Would be really useful and constructive.

Comment: Dear Jacob, sorry for the delay, in fact I couldn't test it yet. I hope I can test during this day.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about RedHat (see comments by OP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to check the folder's content at certain intervals, and compare the list of files with the last check. Since only new files need to be converted, files that were already in the list the last time can be skipped.

That is what the script below does. It is in python, but the principle is the same in any language.

What it does:

When the script initiates, it makes a list of files in the directory.
Then, in a loop, every 5 seconds:

- it checks for additional files
- if additional files were found, they will be converted, files that were already there are skipped.
- it sets the last checked file list to be the "new" initial file list.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time

directory = "/path/to/your/files"

def current_files():
    read = subprocess.check_output(["ls", directory]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    return [item for item in read.split("\n")]

initial_files = current_files()

while True:
    update = current_files()
    for item in update:
        if (item in initial_files, item.startswith("frm")) == (False, True):
            subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", "dos2unix", directory+"/"+item])
    initial_files = update
    time.sleep(5)
```

Copy the script into an empty file, set the path to your folder, save it as `convert.py`,  and run the script in the background by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/convert.py
```

Comment: here's the output when executing script:                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/convert.py", line 12, in ?
    initial_files = current_files()
  File "/root/Desktop/convert.py", line 9, in current_files
    read = subprocess.check_output(["ls", directory]).decode("utf-8").strip()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

Comment: i'm using redhat and when executing "python3" in command line doesn't work. i have to make "python"

Comment: @DJames Appearantly Redhat does not come with python3. I could not know you were using redhat. python(2) does not come with subprocess' check_output. You should have mentioned it.

Comment: yes in fact it was my mistake...

Comment: I've tested in ubuntu and it works!

Answer (score 0):

A fragile way using [`inotifywait`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/inotifywait) and `awk`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/path/to/folder"
while FILE="$(inotifywait '$DIR'  -e close_write --format '%e,%f' | awk -F, '$NF ~ /^frm/{print $NF}')"
do     
    echo $FILE; 
    if [[ -f $FILE ]]
    then
        dos2unix "$DIR/$FILE"
    fi    
done
```

Notes:

- You need to install `inotify-tools`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
  ```
- This watches only the `close_write` event, so `dos2unix` would happen after the process that created or modified it closed the file.
- You could also watch the directory recursively using the `-r` option.
- `inotifywait` has an `--exclude` option which accepts POSIX-extended regular expressions, but negating a regex (everything except `frm`) is complicated, and more easily done in `awk`.
- This will break if filenames contain a comma `,`. Pick a delimiter in the `--format` string which is guaranteed not to appear in a filename.

Comment: i'm using redhat...in fact I use inotify-tools to check new files in a folder and the display a message to user...in ubuntu! works like a charm...